# How to add text component into gameobject at runtime using c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working in unity to develop some VR rooms. but I need to know how to add text component into a game object at runtime any examples PLZ.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a TextMesh you can add it like that, if you want to add something else you can change the generic parameter to the behaviour you want to add:

```
this.gameObject.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
```

Comment: ok, I need to add game object inside of game object at runtime give some example. because I am not a developer that only.

Comment: You dont need to add a gameObject. Inside your monobehaviour that should add the Text, you can just paste the line I have inside that behaviour.

Comment: thanks. now I need to bind second value but second value also bind the same position. how to change second text component different position. my canvas is World space mode.